# Async await issue on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm learning to use async/await and this is quite confused to me. As I know, `async` functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

```
async function foo() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        throw new Error('error');
    }, 5000);
}

async function test() {
    try {
        await foo();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('not reached');
}

test();
```

- **Expected output:** log the error after 5 secs, then log "not reach".
- **What actually happened:** "not reach" gets logged right after I start the script, then the error gets logged after 5 seconds.
- **Attempts:** the following code does exactly what I want, but I don't know what's the difference between those code.
- **Environment**: nodejs 16.14.2

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error('foo'));
        }, 5000);
    });
}

async function test() {
    try {
        await foo();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('not reached');
}

test();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-event-loop-explained-4cd26af121d4                   this might help you out in getting a better understanding

Comment: The `async` keyword alone isn't enough to make your function asynchronous. `async` is just syntactical sugar for a function returning a promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### foo needs to actually resolve

Your example doesn't work because `foo` doesn't actually care about the timeout. It just starts the timeout then returns immediately. What you need to do is make `foo` resolve *when the timeout fires*, which actually requires you to construct a Promise explicitly.

```js
async function foo() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
  })
}
```

Since you return a Promise, you could technically not declare `foo` as async, but it doesn't matter, and (I think) it's still helpful for other developers to see that the function returns a Promise without having to look through the implementation.

Comment: So what happens in the first example is that the Promise resolves immediately after the call to foo(), then the timer starts -> console.log() function ?

Comment: Not quite. First the timer starts, then execution reaches the end of the async function body which causes `foo` to resolve. So, `foo` technically waits as long as it takes to _initiate_ a timeout (which is <0 ms).

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, foo returns a promise, setTimeout needs to produce a promise for it to work in your example.

For example

```
async function foo() {
  // promise returned
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve() } , 5000)
  })
}
```

Comment: Unluckily, Tom was a little faster than you. Please delete your answer as it duplicates his.